# Writing extension methods utilizing objects from Factory in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, extension-methods, factory-pattern

I'm facing a design question on how to properly integrate an object that originates from a factory into extension methods.

Say I have object Foo, I get Foo via a factory method like TopLevelStatic.GetFoo().
Foo has a framework worth of functionality in it, again implemented as a factory.

```
Foo.GetBar();
Foo.GetBaz();
Foo.GetBaz().GetBiz();
```

Say I want to write a bunch of extension methods around objects that would need Foo, like:

```
public static MyObj ToMyObj(this Biz biz, Foo foo){      
    return new MyObj(biz + foo.GetBar());
}
```

Now the issue that I find myself in, is that virtually all the extension methods i'm writing require Foo in some capacity, which makes me question whether the extensions should actually hang of of Foo as the top level object and not the logical location of a related object like Biz(MyObj has some business logic relationship with Biz).

Do I just pass Foo to all my extension methods? That feels wrong. How do I effectively static-afy an object whos lifetime i don't control. Would it be semantically ok to implement a singleton that throws an exception of GetInstance if it's _self has not yet been set by some other code?
Is there a way to do this with DI since there is no constructor, or actual object that holds the extension method

Comment: Why dont you want to call TopLevelStatic.GetFoo() within the extension methods?

Comment: primarily because TopLevelStatic.GetFoo() is actually tied to the context to which it is invoked in, essentially to a system resource, selection of which happens via ui, so I'm not guaranteed to get the same object every time

Comment: But this is fine, isn't it? You will have the same context when you call your extension method.

Comment: Not necessarily, think of a utility that attaches to a running process based on the process name, if there are more then one processes running by the same name, i might get a different one every time I call it. Essentially, I need the first instance i get when I call it for the first time to be a singleton.

Comment: Can you update both `Bar` to include a reference to its parent `Foo` and have the method `Foo.GetBar` set that reference?  Then you're extension method body would be `return new MyObj(biz + biz.Foo.GetBar());`

Comment: @ppittle what do you mean by update? Extend? I don't have access to the implementation.

Comment: You could try using a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) in your extension method. Thus you will give both your Foo and Bar objects only once to your extension method: public static FooBar Combine(this Tuple<Foo, Bar> tuple)